# Cannot log my superuser in ( custom user model / manager )

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build super user using a custom user model and a custom user manager. I did exactly the same thing than the django doc about the create_superuser method and in my shell, I'm able to create a superuser with an email and a password. But when I try to log in on the django admin page, I have this wierd error :

> Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note
>   that both fields may be case-sensitive.

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    #custom create_user method
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password = password
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    #Custom create_super_user method
    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            password = password
        )
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        #setting up Choices for interest, Must add other fields ...
        MATHS = 'mat'
        PHYSICS = 'phy'
        HISTORY = 'his'
        BIOLOGIE = 'bio'
        ECONOMICS = 'eco'
        POLITICS = 'pol'
        MUSIC = 'mus'
        ENGLISH = 'eng'
        FRENCH = 'fra'
        SPANISH = 'spa'
        LAW = 'law'
        COMPUTER_SCIENCE = 'cs'
        COMMUNICATION = 'com'
        MARKETING = 'mar'
        SPORT = 'spo'
        INTERESTS_CHOICES = (
            (MATHS, 'Maths'),
            (PHYSICS, 'Physics'),
            (HISTORY, 'History'),
            (BIOLOGIE, 'Biologie'),
            (ECONOMICS, 'Economics'),
            (POLITICS, 'Politics'),
            (MUSIC, 'Music'),
            (ENGLISH, 'English'),
            (FRENCH, 'French'),
            (SPANISH, 'Spanish'),
            (LAW, 'Law'),
            (COMPUTER_SCIENCE, 'Computer Science'),
            (COMMUNICATION, 'Communication'),
            (MARKETING, 'Marketing'),
            (SPORT, 'Sport')
        )
        interests = MultiSelectField(
            max_length = 2,
            choices = INTERESTS_CHOICES
        )


        #Setting up a Ranking System
        RANKING_CHOICES = [
            ('silver', 'Silver'),
            ('gold', 'Gold'),
            ('platinium', 'Platinium'),
            ('diamond', 'Diamond')
        ]

        email = models.EmailField(
            max_length=50,
            unique=True
        )
        username = models.CharField(
            max_length=25,
            unique=True,
            null=True,
            blank=True
        )
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
        birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        reputation = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        rank = models.CharField(choices=RANKING_CHOICES, max_length=1)
        staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        bio = models.TextField(
            max_length=300,
            default="",
            blank=True
        )
        objects = UserManager()
        #Setting email to be the main source of authentication
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

        #Super User Only
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

        #def get_absolute_url(self):
            #use reverse + nom de l'url de view

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email

        def get_full_name(self):
            return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

        def get_short_name(self):
            return self.first_name

        def get_username(self):
            return self.username

        def set_user_league(self):
            if 15 <= self.reputation < 40:
                self.rank = "gold"
            elif 40 <= self.reputation < 80:
                self.rank = "platinium"
            else:
                self.rank = "diamond"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a password by *calling* `.set_password(..)`, not assigning a new value:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    #custom create_user method
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

The default `create_superuser` will set `is_staff` and `is_superuser` to `True` as well:

```
#Custom create_super_user method
def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email = self.normalize_email(email),
        password = password
    )
    user.admin = user.is_superuser = user.is_staff = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Comment: How should I change that ? I followed the django documentation

Comment: @Valentin: you wrote `user.set_password = password` (that is probably something you copied the wrong way)?

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the flag **is_superuser** to True, in order to make user a superuser in system. Please find the below code:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    """
    create and save superuser
    """
    user = self.create_user(
                 self.normalize_email(email), password=password)
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```